Bug in the implementation of system, dark and light mode where system theme isn't getting applied to the sheet
I am implementing a picker view which has 3 options: system, light and dark mode. Whenever an option is selected, it gets persisted to whole app by the use of @AppStorage.
Light mode and dark mode options are working as expected. But the system option isn't working as expected. The Content View reflects the system theme color but I have to dismiss my sheet view and open it again in order to reflect the selected theme color. I have attached a gif file displaying the issue.
Attached is the code for 3 different files:

ContentView.swift:

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Main View")
            Button("Show Sheet!") {
                showSheet = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            SheetView()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


demoApp.swift

import SwiftUI

@main
struct demoApp: App {
    @AppStorage("currentThemeKey") private var selectedTheme = AppTheme.system

    private var selectedColorScheme: ColorScheme? {
        switch selectedTheme {
        case .system:
            return .none
        case .light:
            return .light
        case .dark:
            return .dark
        }
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .preferredColorScheme(selectedColorScheme)
        }
    }
}


SheetView.swift

import SwiftUI

enum AppTheme: String, CaseIterable {
    case system, light, dark
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @AppStorage("currentThemeKey") private var selectedTheme = AppTheme.system
    
    private var selectedColorScheme: ColorScheme {
        switch selectedTheme {
        case .system:
            return UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? .dark : .light
        case .light:
            return .light
        case .dark:
            return .dark
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Text("Sheet View")
                Picker("App Theme", selection: $selectedTheme) {
                    ForEach(AppTheme.allCases, id: \.self) {
                        Text("\($0)".capitalized)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    SheetView()
}



You can include .preferredColorScheme(selectedColorScheme) in your SheetView body and it will work as expected.
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        Form {
            Text("Sheet View")
            Picker("App Theme", selection: $selectedTheme) {
                ForEach(AppTheme.allCases, id: \.self) {
                    Text("\($0)".capitalized)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .preferredColorScheme(selectedColorScheme)
}

According to the .preferredColorScheme(_:) documentation,

Use one of the values in ColorScheme with this modifier to set a
preferred color scheme for the nearest enclosing presentation, like a
popover, a sheet, or a window.

Since a sheet is considered a different presentation, it requires this manual change to apply the color scheme correctly.

One thing to be noted here is that if we add any other kind of environment variable in the sheet view such as:
@Environment(.dismiss) var dismiss
It again breaks functionality for .system option
